# Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable! Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am getting an error in angular 4 after adding some new html code, earlier the form was working fine. I tried commenting the new the code but its still isnt working - what to do - I researched this error and tried solving but nothing helped - nor am I getting the exact location of the problem

My Code:

```
<form role="form" #adminForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logAdmin(adminForm.form)">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="adminUsername" #adminUsername="ngModel" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="adminUsername"
              required>
            <div *ngIf="adminUsername.touched && adminUsername.errors">
              <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="adminUsername.errors.required">Username is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="passwordText" #adminPassword="ngModel" id="adminPassword" name="adminPassword" placeholder="Password"
              type="password" required>
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="adminPassword.touched && adminPassword.errors">Password is required</div>
          <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-yellow" [disabled]="!adminForm.valid">Log In</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Error I am getting :

```
Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
    at _AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:26550:23)
    at PropertyWrite.visit (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:4895:24)
    at convertActionBinding (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:26000:45)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28519:22)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ViewBuilder._createElementHandleEventFn (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28515:18)
    at nodes.(anonymous function) (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:27934:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28460:22)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ViewBuilder._createNodeExpressions (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28459:56)
    at _AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:26550:23)
    at PropertyWrite.visit (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:4895:24)
    at convertActionBinding (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:26000:45)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28519:22)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ViewBuilder._createElementHandleEventFn (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28515:18)
    at nodes.(anonymous function) (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:27934:27)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28460:22)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ViewBuilder._createNodeExpressions (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:28459:56)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:824:31)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:795:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:873:17)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4944:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:36)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:602:35)
    at <anonymous>
```

I searched on internet and found questions & answer for the same error - but I didnt got any solution which worked for me ... Thats why this error might be repeated but the answer seems to be different then many out there.

Comment: Q&A are welcomed, but make sure you search first, there are other questions and answers for this ;)

Comment: If you mark this as a duplicate, aren't you supposed to give us the question for which this is the duplicate?

Answer (score 412, accepted):

The issue is that I had renamed the ngModel variable name exactly same

```
[(ngModel)]="adminUsername" #adminUsername="ngModel"
```

The Solution which worked for me

```
[(ngModel)]="adminUsernameText" #adminUsername="ngModel"
```

Comment: Great .. the error gone. then how to validate that in different names

Comment: @PonmariSubramanian - #adminUsername will be used inside the html code for validation checks and adminUsernameText is the variable in your ts file and it will be used there by other functions and code - by the way, adminUsernameText indicates two way binding of angular - I hope you got the point

Comment: @AbdealiChandanwala Thanks,I check with my code.It's working.

Comment: I think it's annoying that the error-message doesn't contain the reference to where the problem occurred.

Comment: Why haven't this mentioned in the documentations?

Comment: Note that you also get this error when attempting to assign a value to a context-given variable in the template -- something like `let-localVar="outsideVar"` and attempting to do something like `(click)="localVar = !localVar"`

Comment: Refer this link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32695

Comment: Angular team could've emitted a better error message.... very cryptic error, thanks for the post and answer!